# Does php-cli have its own binary?

Tags: php

1- When running php cli, does this use the same main php binary used by web servers (for example php cgi or php-fpm), or it's a seperate binary?

2- When installing php as fpm, two packages are required, php and php-fpm, so what's the difference between the two?
thanks...

Answer (score 2):

For sure each of them could use different `php.ini` configuration file therefore each of them could behave differently, ie using different binaries, modules, etc.

Create a file `phpinfo.php` in your web root with content:

```
<?php 
echo phpinfo();
```

and run it:

- via GLI using http://localhost/phpinfo.php
- via CLI using `php /path/to/your/web/root/phpinfo.php`
- or call from your terminal `php -i`

And compare the differences.

Note: to quickly find what *.ini files are in use you could:

- call function `print_r(php_ini_loaded_file());` in your GLI script
- call `php --ini` in your terminal CLI